# gitlab pipeline pending, failed

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

[pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4Fna.png)
[more information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6DAE.png)

I am learning to create pipelines.
Created a simple pipeline.
Created a runner.
But the pipeline is not being executed.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems OK to me and looks like it did execute at least one time in your pipeline. Maybe your runner stopped running unexpectedly? Or maybe it's busy running another job?

Comment: Why your runner has `127.0.0.1` IP address?

Comment: Runner started. 127.0.0.1 because it is running on the same machine as gitlab

Comment: Is there any information written why the job failed? See documenation where to find this information: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/#see-why-a-job-failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I found out that the runner was registered with no root and this caused problems.